# How to set automatic focus to Java applet on js

Tags: java, javascript, applet, focus

I made an applet. It's starting when web page is loaded. But applet lost focus, when web page lost focus too and need to click on area of applet and then it gained focus.
I'm tried variants but it's not helpful

```
document.getElementById(appletId).focus();
document.getElementById(appletId).requestFocus();
```

How to set focus to applet in java script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Ensure the applet element in the HTML declares `scriptable=true`
- Add a public method to the applet that calls `requestFocusInWindow()`.
- Call that method using JavaScript.
- Be sure to have the JS console open for run time debugging.